# I've created multiple filters functions and each one does its own job right, however, I'm not sure how to chain them so they all work together

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create filtering functionality which would allow me to filter cards from a collectible card game based on several criteria. I've already created 6 functions which filter based on a single criteria like card name, card cost or card rarity. These functions work fine and do their job, however, right now I can only use one of them at a time.

What I am trying to do is combine or chain these functions so that they are all taken into account before returning the final array with cards. I'm wondering if there's any easy way to do that?

Right now I have this:

```
<template>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="cards-list">
            <div class="card" v-for='card in filteredByCost' @click='specificCard(card.cardCode)'>
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img class='responsive-image' :src='"../assets/cards/" + card.cardCode + ".png"' alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import cards from '../assets/cards/set1-en_us.json'
    import router from '../router'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cards: cards,
                search: '',
                regions: ['Demacia', 'Noxus'],
                cost: [7],
                attack: [3, 5],
                health: [4, 7],
                rarity: ['Champion']
            }
        },
        methods: {
            specificCard(cardCode){
                router.push({ name: 'specificCard', params: { cardCode: cardCode } })
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filteredByName(){
                return this.cards.filter((card) => {
                    return card.name.match(this.search)
                })
            },
            filteredByRegion(){
                return this.cards.filter((card) => {
                    return this.regions.includes(card.region)
                })
            },
            filteredByCost(){
                return this.cards.filter((card) => {
                    return this.cost.includes(card.cost)
                })
            },
            filteredByRarity(){
                return this.cards.filter((card) => {
                    return this.rarity.includes(card.rarity)
                })
            },
            filteredByAttack(){
                return this.cards.filter((card) => {
                    return this.attack.includes(card.attack)
                })
            },
            filteredByHealth(){
                return this.cards.filter((card) => {
                    return this.health.includes(card.health)
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: These aren't Vue filters - what you have are computed properties that return an array that is filtered

Comment: also, instead of importing and using `router`, you can just use `this.$router`

Comment: to answer your question: create a computed method to combine this. My vue experience is a year past, but I believe you can use your computed  properties inside computed properties so yo can combine them in a new computed property (if that makes sense)

Comment: @bobimaru Two questions: (1) Do you determine which filters are active if the corresponding property is non-null (e.g. if rarity was `null`, then that filter is off)? (2) Do you want the intersection or the union of the filters?

Comment: @DavidWeldon (1) I think if the corresponding property value is null, that means the filter should be off, it just seems like the most logical thing .I assume intersection would mean that only cards that meet all criteria should be returned, whereas union would be all cards that match at least 1 criteria? If that's the case, I'd say intersection is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Information

1. Place all your filter methods in the `methods` attribute on the vue instance
2. Create a way to enable/disable the filters
3. Create a computed property that looks at your #2 in this list and applies the proper filters accordingly

### My rough example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      filterEnabler: {
        search: false,
        sort: false
      },
      formInputs: {
        searchText: ''
      },
      entries: [
        'vue',
        'react',
        'angular',
        'svelte'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredEntries () {
      let { entries, filterEnabler } = this
      entries = entries.slice(0)
      
      if (filterEnabler.search) entries = this.searchFilter(entries)
      if (filterEnabler.sort) entries = this.sortFilter(entries)
      
      return entries
    }
  },
  methods: {
    searchFilter (entries) {
      return entries.filter(entry => entry.indexOf(this.formInputs.searchText) !== -1)
    },
    sortFilter (entries) {
      return entries.sort()
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="search-filter">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="filterEnabler.search" /> Search Filter
      <div v-if="filterEnabler.search">
        <input placeholder="type here" type="text" v-model="formInputs.searchText" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-filter">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="filterEnabler.sort" /> Sort Filter
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="entry in filteredEntries" :key="entry">{{entry}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my example, you can see this I have 2 filters, `search` and `sort` - when one of their `filterEnablers` is toggeled `true`, it will apply all the enabled filters to the data and then return a new, separate array (very important, try not to mutate your source of truth, in my case, that's `entries`)

Hope this helps!